# Cosets of $SL^\pm (n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Here is the question I am struggling with.  If anyone could just give a push in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Let $\mathbf{H} = SL^\pm (n,\mathbb{R})$
Given $A$, $B \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, prove that $A\mathbf{H}=B\mathbf{H}$ if and only if $\det(A) = \pm \det(B)$.

Comment: I think $A\mathbf{H} = B\mathbf{H}$ if and only if $A^{-1}B \in \mathbf{H}$.

Comment: BTW, that is not the special linear group, which contains *only* matrices whose determinant is $\;1\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John commented:

$$AH=BH\iff B^{-1}A\in H\iff \det(B^{-1}A)=\pm 1$$

But the product theorem tells us that $\;\det(B^{-1}A)=\det B^{-1}\cdot\det A\;$ , so...

Comment: I am probably just being dense right now, perhaps due to the hour, but why is it that $AH=BH \iff B^{-1}A\in H$? From there the rest is clear.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: It's the definition of the equivalence relation wrt some subgroup of a group, of which the equivalence classes are precisely the left (or right) cosets.